# How can I add transitions between views/pages when I use SwipeGestureRecognizer in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, swipe-gesture

I am using ContentView inside a ContentPage like this

```
<ContentView x:Name="MyContent"
                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer Swiped="SwipLeft" Direction="Left"/>
                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer Swiped="SwipRight" Direction="Right"/>
                </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
 </ContentView>
```

in the code behind I set the relavent Content to the ContentView according to the SwipeDirection like below. and same as for SwipRight.

```
private void SwipLeft(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
        {
            
                if (e.Direction == SwipeDirection.Left)
                {
                   //set the relavent page content here               
                }                                      
        }
```

I need to set an animation or transition to appear when I swipe between pages. I need this only for iOS. Can anyone help me for this or any method knows anyone to achieve this?

you can get the idea from this snapshot
[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT5uj.png)
all the content and everything has done I just need to add transitions between pages.

Comment: Have you tried using a CarouselView? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/.
You cannot customise the animation but it does work.

Comment: Your screen shot look like tab control. Is that you want?

Comment: @xerx Yes. I tied with that. but it is not fulfilled my all requirements. so i just get rid of that

Comment: @Anand yes. I need tabbed pages for iOS with top tabs and this is a sub page of a main page. I have done tabbed pages with customization. now I just need to add some transitions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **TabbedPage** . It seems that you want to let the tab display on the top of screen . In your case you could install the plugin **TopTabbedPage** from nuget .

#### Usage

```
<forms:TopTabbedPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Naxam.Demo.TestPage"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Naxam.Demo"
    xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Naxam.Controls.Forms;assembly=Naxam.TopTabbedPage.Forms"
    BarTextColor="#00b9e1"
    BarIndicatorColor="#00b9e1"
    BarBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
    Title="MyRide">
    <views:Page1 />  // here is the content page , you need to put each contentview in independent ContenPage
    <views:Page2 />
</forms:TopTabbedPage>
```

And in iOS project -> AppDelegate.cs

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method
        TopTabbedRenderer.Init();
       
        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        LoadApplication(new App());

  
        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

For more details about the plugin you could refer the [github project site](https://github.com/NAXAM/toptabbedpage-xamarin-forms) .

Comment: I tried with this TopTabbedPage. unfortunately it works only for main page. But i need this tabbed page in a sub page. I have done with this some customization. It all works fine. I just only need to add some transitions when you swipe from let to right and right to left.

Comment: `MyContent.Opacity = 0;
MyContent.FadeTo (1, 000);` 
I tried something like this it works fine. But I need a transition like moving page from left to right/right to left

Comment: You could use ScrollView or CarouselView .